# Extensions of Carathéodory's theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, banach-spaces, convex-analysis

We know about the [Carathéodory's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_%28convex_hull%29) which is on the convex bodies of $\mathbb{R}^d$. My question is, how far we can extend it? Is it true for say, any convex object of Banach space, or for convex objects of any real manifold?

I believe the answers are negative. However I want to know whether there is a similar result like Carathéodory (i.e. an upper bound with respect to dimension of the space/manifold). Advanced thanks for any help/suggestion/reference which can be (relatively) easily understood. Feel free to ask (and also edit) if you want more clarification.

Comment: One possible direction you might try is [Choquet Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choquet_theory), though I can't think of any results that are directly analogous.

Comment: @icurays1 thanks for mentioning. however, i am not very sure whether there is any analogous result. i am trying to read some basic texts on it though.

Comment: It seems that already in $l^2$ the convex hull of the standard basis $B$ is not a convex hull of any finite subset of $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is one [here](http://qjmath.oxfordjournals.org/content/22/2/231.full.pdf). As I'm not from maths background so won't be able to explain the paper. There is another nice work [Approximate proof for Carathéodory's theorem](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2296) which gives a epsilon-approx being INDEPENDENT of the dimension of the set